# phonegap 4.0 media plugin ReferenceError: Media is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio

I am fairly new to programming, and I am trying to build my very first phonegap app. I am trying to play some sounds which are located in my /www/sounds/ folder. However, when I am running index.html in my browser (chrome) I get the 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined" error.

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <!--jQuery mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="files-list-page" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>Fragmenten</h1>
    </header>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="files-list" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="false" data-split-icon="delete">
            <audio id="fr1" src="sounds/5euros.mp3" type="audio/mp3" ></audio>
        </ul>
        <button id="btn1" class=ui-btn" onclick="playAudio('sounds/5euros.mp3')">Play</button>
    </div>
    <footer data-role="footer">
        <h3 id="copyright-title">Soundboard</h3>
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
```

And this is my JS:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}


};

app.initialize();


// Play audio
//
function playAudio(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function () {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        }
    );
    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

My config.xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.martijn.HuisbaasBob" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HuisbaasBob</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Any suggestions would be of great help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed the media plugin ?

Comment: Yes i did, using the CLI : cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media

Comment: Check "config.xml" whether it configured properly or not. or just share ur config.xml

Comment: Posted my config.xml, it is pretty basic i did not change anything. Figured that installing the plugin via the CLI imported the plugin in my project.

Comment: Phonegap plugins do not work in browsers. You need test with a device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this lines in ur config.xml to get your plugin worked...

**(in app/res/xml/config.xml)**

```
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
</feature>
```

"Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined" mean your code couldn't able to recognize it... meaning "not configured"

Comment: Hey, that did not work out. Or should I try and build the application first?

Comment: So where are you running? in computer browser?